# asp.net bind a gridview and change its style

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, data-binding

i have a gridview which is binded to a table in sql server . i wrote a c# code at code behind i.e :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconectionstring"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select fldCompany,fldModel 'مدل',fldYear 'سال',fldPrice 'قیمت',fldCountPhoto  'تعداد عکس',fldActive  'موقعیت نمایش' from tbl_Usercar where fldTbl_UserID =@fldTbl_UserID", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fldTbl_UserID", Session["se_userID"] as string);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

         da.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource=ds;

         GridView1.DataBind();


    }
```

now my table appear as i want to but i cant change my gridview style Eg i can't change the Columns color or font and etc . i tried to use my datasource and make  attribute in my asp page but it will show each Columns 2 times .

please help me to fix this problem . Thank you

Comment: If you use Visual Basic, you can change the colour from the design view

Comment: You will need to set the "autogeneratecolumns" to false so that your columns don't appear twice. Then you can specify a CSS class for each column if you wish, and style this with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have something like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="YourGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false"></asp:GridView>
```

And then you can style using the `YourGridView` in the CSS.

Comment: Thank you , that was the exact thing that i was looking for :)